# What is the correct format for a directory path when using PHP's opendir()?

Tags: php, filepath, opendir

I'm having trouble with my filepath when using `opendir()`. I get the following warning:

> PHP Warning:  opendir(/uploads/users/405/images/profile/profilepic/)
>   [function.opendir]: failed to open dir:
>   No such file or directory in
>   /home/my_folder/public_html/models/photos.php on line 1059

line 1059 in *`photos.php`* has the following:

```
if ( ( $handle = opendir( $profile_pic_path ) ) ) { // do stuff }
```

where:

```
$profile_pic_path = '/uploads/users/405/images/profile/profilepic/';
```

I've tried several different things, but I can't get it to work (I keep getting the PHP Warning message in my error log).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does that directory actually exist? A directory named `uploads` in the filesystem root would be pretty strange on most systems.

Comment: The format is correct. Are you sure that the uploads folder is located in the webroot

Comment: Yes, ``uploads`` is in ``public_html``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/` in the begining of path means - absolute path.

you should use absolute or relative path:

```
$profile_pic_path = dirname(__FILE__).'/uploads/users/405/images/profile/profilepic/';
```

or

```
$profile_pic_path = 'uploads/users/405/images/profile/profilepic/';
```

this works if your script in the same directory where uploads dir is.

in case if your script in subdirectory (lib/tests/test.php for example), and you have no global $basepath initialised:

```
$profile_pic_path = dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))
                    .'/uploads/users/405/images/profile/profilepic/';
```

often somewhere in top of logic here is global or constant basedir used (say in config/main.php) :

```
global $basedir=dirname(dirname((__FILE__));
```